# CDN Tax Receipt, attach receipts to automated workflow messages ... sometimes?

Tags: civicontribute, cdn-tax-receipts

Is there a way to send out automated cdn tax receipts, but only selectively? e.g. if a site has options for cc and ach/eft, then only send them out immediately for cc?

Or, in the case of the client who's asking, they're interested in not sending them out for larger donations, and also not for recurring donations (so that they can send out a single one at the end of the year)?

I think that answer is no, but it seems to me that it should be possible without too much work, analogous to how there's an advanced setting for deciding whether a contribution is tax receiptable.

Comment: Here's the spot in the code where it looks like the answer is no: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cdntaxreceipts/-/blob/master/cdntaxreceipts.php#L371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but it could be done by turning off the setting, and then having a home-made script run periodically and send receipts for contributions based on criteria of your choosing (basically the same code you would have to write to put in a hook if it existed, plus the call to send the email).

Comment: So, kind of an in-between behaviour, not immediately, but only slightly asynchronously. Which has the advantage of not breaking things if mail is temporarily unavailable. Sounds like it could be a job api!